# Unable to import tensorflow, 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm trying to import tensorflow in jupyter notebook(Conda). Previously worked fine, but now I'm getting an error,

AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '**reduce_cython**'

tensorflow version 2.6

Comment: I tried (base) pip install --upgrade h5py --user
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\users\sahan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.5 in c:\users\sahan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from h5py) (1.20.1)

Comment: and again now it's working

Comment: If you upgrade something that you have already imported, it's normal that you have to restart Python (restart the kernel) to pick it up.Thanks!